# ItemReader unable to read rows via PrestoDriver

Tags: spring, spring-batch, presto, presto-jdbc

The following ItemReader bean read rows via PrestDriver. When executing the batch I am getting the this error message:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

.....

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Attempt to process next row 
failed; SQL [SELECT * FROM ......]; getRow; nested exception is 
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: getRow
```

ItemReader code

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<ExportDto> itemReader() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:presto: ");
    dataSource.setUsername("....");
    dataSource.setPassword("....");

    JdbcCursorItemReader<ExportDto> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<ExportDto>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setSql("SELECT * FROM .....'");
    BeanPropertyRowMapper<ExportDto> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(ExportDto.class);
    reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
    return reader;
}
```

I have created an “hello world” app in order to test the driver, this time using plain JDBCDriver. This test was successful.

```
 String url = "jdbc:presto:.....";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("user", "....");
    properties.setProperty("password", "....");
    properties.setProperty("SSL", "true");
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        if (conn == null) {
            System.out.print("NULL");
        } else {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT distinct .....";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            // Extract data from result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                // Retrieve by column name
                String programs = rs.getString("prg");
            }
            // Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
```

Any ideas why this happen? or some workarounds will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The method isn't yet supported in Presto JDBC driver. Filed an issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/5745.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `JdbcCursorItemReader` verifies the cursor's position after each processed row. This check involves a [call to ResultSet#getRow()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/e7ea16c9bc8bb3cbe174c8b190fff206b957e1bc/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.java#L384) which does not seem to be supported as mentioned in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601558/itemreader-unable-to-read-rows-via-prestodriver#comment114227662_64601558).

You can disable this check using `JdbcCursorItemReader#setVerifyCursorPosition` until this feature is supported in the Presto Driver.